# How to form array of arrays in typescript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have two arrays,

```
arr1 = [1589135400000, 1589221800000, 1589308200000, 1589394600000, 1589481000000, 1589567400000, 1589653800000, 1589740200000, 1589826600000, 1591122600000]'    
arr2 = [90.05, 98.0225, 99.8231, 99.3969, 73.45, 68.356, 55.123, 100, 68.75, 98.02430  ]
```

i need  to form array of arrays which should look like this.

```
[
      [1589135400000, 90.05],
      [1589221800000, 98.0225],
      [1589308200000, 99.8231],
      [1589394600000, 99.3969],
      [1589481000000, 73.45],
      [1589567400000, 68.356],
      [1589653800000, 55.123],
      [1589740200000, 100],
      [1589826600000, 68.75],
      [1591122600000, 98.02430]

     
]
```

I am using typescript.
please some one help me to solve this.please please
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `arr1.map((v, i) => [v, arr2[i]])`

Comment: FYI, the question and the result you ask for aren't the same thing. It looks like what you want is to make an array of arrays from two arrays, in which the two arrays are mapped on the overall index o each other...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to combine the array values at the same index.

```js
const arr1 = [
  1589135400000,
  1589221800000,
  1589308200000,
  1589394600000,
  1589481000000,
  1589567400000,
  1589653800000,
  1589740200000,
  1589826600000,
  1591122600000,
];

const arr2 = [
  90.05,
  98.0225,
  99.8231,
  99.3969,
  73.45,
  68.356,
  55.123,
  100,
  68.75,
  98.02430,
];

const combined = arr1.map((n, i) => [n, arr2[i]]);

console.log(combined);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop over the first and find the same index in the second

```js
arr1 = [1589135400000, 1589221800000, 1589308200000, 1589394600000, 1589481000000, 1589567400000, 1589653800000, 1589740200000, 1589826600000, 1591122600000]
arr2 = [90.05, 98.0225, 99.8231, 99.3969, 73.45, 68.356, 55.123, 100, 68.75, 98.02430 ]

console.log(arr1.map((el, i) => [ el, arr2[i] ]))
```